# lifting a closed curve

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, loop-spaces

Is it always true (because of covering spaces has homotopy lifting property)?

**loop $f$ lifts to a closed curve if and only if any curve freely homotopic to $f$ lifts to a closed curve.**

or we have to assume that cover is normal? (In that case could anyone present any counterexample and proof of this fact for normal cover)

I ask because I found a Remark:

> Since the cover in the conclusion of Lemma 2.1 is **normal**, a closed
>   curve $f$ lifts to a closed curve if and only if any curve freely
>   homotopic to $f$ lifts to a closed curve.

I found it in the paper: Malestein, Justin, Putman, Andrew; On the self-intersections of curves deep in the lower central series of a surface group. Geom. Dedicata 149 (2010), 73–84. which is available [here.](http://www.math.rice.edu/~andyp/papers/SelfIntersections.pdf)

Comment: Only for regular covers (people usually do not call them normal).

Comment: @studiosus Could you say more? Do you know any simple counterexample? Can you say where I can find a proof of this fact for regular covers?

Comment: @studiosus They are called normal covering spaces in Hatcher.  After all, $p_*(\pi_1(\widetilde{X}))$ is normal in $\pi_1(X)$.